Guru Meditation Error: Core 0 panic'ed (LoadProhibited). Exception was unhandled. Core 0 register dump: PC : 0x4003f3c8 PS :
After submitting the values in web server,the wifi will turn into OFF state.After that im getting this error.This error causes esp32 starts rebooting and starts running from beginning of program
Tried: I have created ESP32 Async web server to set the time and date in esp32.After giving values ,the esp32 is turning into OFF state.But after that because of error.The esp32 starts rebooting and starts from beginning
Expecting:
After the wifi is disabled ,the values which are given in web server will be used to set the time of esp32.based on those values,the esp32 should calculate the current time.
This is my main.cpp file
#include<stdio.h>
#include<Arduino.h>
#include "../include/spa.h"
#include "../include/wifiModule.h"
#include "../include/timeFile.h"

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(10);
  Serial.println("Setup complete.");
  Serial.println("Press the button to ON the  Wi-Fi");
  LittleFSFiles();
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  Serial.print("Free heap memory: ");
  Serial.println(ESP.getFreeHeap());
  wifiResult();
  spa_result();
  delay(500);
}

void LittleFSFiles()
{
   if(!LittleFS.begin())
  {
    Serial.println("Failed to mount LittleFS");
    return;
  }
  else
  {
    Serial.println("LittleFS mounted successfully.");
  }
  server.on("/index.css",HTTP_GET,[](AsyncWebServerRequest *request)
  {
    request->send(LittleFS,"/index.css","text/css");
  });
   server.on("/", HTTP_GET, [](AsyncWebServerRequest *request){
    request->send(LittleFS,"/index.html","text/html");
  });  
}

This is my wifiModule.cpp file
#include "../include/wifiModule.h"
#include "../include/timeFile.h"

const char* ssid = "ESP32_WIFI";      // Your WiFi SSID
const char* password = "esp32_wifi";            // Your WiFi password
bool touchDetected=false;
bool wifiEnabled = false;
unsigned long lastDebounceTime =0;
const unsigned long debounceDelay = 500;
int lastButtonState = HIGH;
void disableWifi();
void ESPAsyncWebServer();
AsyncWebServer server(80);

void WifiStart()
{
  // Start serial communication
  if(wifiEnabled)
  {

    WiFi.softAPdisconnect(true);  // Ensure Wi-Fi is OFF before starting
    WiFi.mode(WIFI_AP);
    if (WiFi.softAP(ssid, password)) {
      IPAddress myIP = WiFi.softAPIP();
      Serial.print("AP IP address: ");
      Serial.println(myIP);
      ESPAsyncWebServer();
    }
    else
    {
      Serial.println("Failed to start AP");
    
    }
  }
  else{
    disableWifi();
  }
}
void ESPAsyncWebServer()
{
  server.on("/submit", HTTP_POST, [](AsyncWebServerRequest *request) {
    String dateTime="", timezone="";
    if (request->hasParam("time", true) && request->hasParam("timezone", true)) {
      dateTime = request->getParam("time", true)->value();
      timezone = request->getParam("timezone", true)->value();
      globalDateTime= dateTime;
      globalTimezone= timezone;
      Serial.print("Date & Time: ");
      Serial.println(globalDateTime);
      Serial.print("Timezone: ");
      Serial.println(globalTimezone);

          
      int year,month, day, hour, minute,second;
      parseDateTime(year,month,day, hour, minute, second);

    }
    request->send(200, "text/plain", "Submitted! Date & Time: " + dateTime + " Timezone: " + timezone);
    // Turn off Wi-Fi as per POST submission
    wifiEnabled = false;
    disableWifi();
    });
      
    server.begin();
    Serial.println("Wi-Fi enabled and AP started.");
}

void disableWifi()
{
  WiFi.disconnect(true);
 
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_OFF);
 
  Serial.println("WiFi disabled.");
}

void wifiResult()
{
  pinMode(TOUCH_PIN,INPUT_PULLUP);
  int buttonState =  digitalRead(TOUCH_PIN);
  Serial.print("Button State: ");
  Serial.println(buttonState);
  if (buttonState != lastButtonState) {
    if(buttonState == LOW )
    {
      if(millis()-lastDebounceTime > debounceDelay){
      wifiEnabled = !wifiEnabled;
      if(wifiEnabled)
      {
        WifiStart();
        Serial.println("Wi-Fi is ON");
      }
      else{
        disableWifi();
        Serial.println("Wi=Fi is OFF");
      }
      lastDebounceTime=millis();
      }
    }
  }
  lastButtonState=buttonState; // Update last button state
}

This is mytimeFile.cpp file
#include<stdio.h>
#include<Arduino.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<sys/time.h>
#include "../include/timeFile.h"

struct tm t;
String globalDateTime="";
String globalTimezone="";

void parseDateTime(int &year, int &month, int &day, int &hour, int &minute, int &second )
{
  Serial.println("Parsing DateTime....");
  Serial.print("globalDateTime: ");
  Serial.println(globalDateTime);
  Serial.print("globalTimezone: ");
  Serial.println(globalTimezone);
  if(globalDateTime.length()>=19 && globalTimezone.length() >=6)
  {
    year = globalDateTime.substring(0,4).toInt();
    month= globalDateTime.substring(5,7).toInt();
    day = globalDateTime.substring(8,10).toInt();

    hour= globalDateTime.substring(11,13).toInt();
    minute=globalDateTime.substring(14,16).toInt();
    second=globalDateTime.substring(17,19).toInt();

    setManualTime(year,month,day,hour,minute,second);
  }
  else
  {
    Serial.println("Error: globalDateTime or globalTimezone foramt is invalid.");
  }
}
void setManualTime(int &year, int &month, int &day, int &hour, int &minute, int &second) {

 
    t.tm_year = year-1900;
    t.tm_mon = month-1;
    t.tm_mday = day;
    t.tm_hour = hour;
    t.tm_min = minute;
    t.tm_sec = second;
    t.tm_isdst = -1;

    time_t timeSinceEpoch = mktime(&t);
    if(timeSinceEpoch == -1)
    {
      Serial.println("Error: Failed to convert time using mktime");
    }
    else
    {
      struct timeval now = {.tv_sec = timeSinceEpoch};
      settimeofday(&now, NULL);
      Serial.println("Manual time added successfully.");
    }
  
  
}

I'm getting this error
Guru Meditation Error: Core  0 panic'ed (LoadProhibited). Exception was unhandled.
Core  0 register dump:
PC      : 0x4003f3c8  PS      : 0x00060a30  A0      : 0x82064318  A1      : 0x3fcaa200
A2      : 0x3fcab9a8  A3      : 0x00000000  A4      : 0x00060a20  A5      : 0x00060e23
A6      : 0x02ced41c  A7      : 0x00ffffff  A8      : 0x00000007  A9      : 0x3fcaa1c0
A10     : 0x3fcab9a8  A11     : 0x3fc99f54  A12     : 0x00000000  A13     : 0x00060a23
A14     : 0x00060a23  A15     : 0x00000001  SAR     : 0x0000001a  EXCCAUSE: 0x0000001c
EXCVADDR: 0x00000130  LBEG    : 0x400570e8  LEND    : 0x400570f3  LCOUNT  : 0x00000000

Backtrace: 0x4003f3c5:0x3fcaa200 0x42064315:0x3fcaa220 0x420220e3:0x3fcaa240 0x4208fa95:0x3fcaa260 0x42031b38:0x3fcaa280 0x4202555d:0x3fcaa2a0 0x42075a80:0x3fcaa2c0 0x42075b25:0x3fcaa300 0x4207640e:0x3fcaa320
  #0  0x42064315 in esp_wifi_internal_free_rx_buffer at ??:?
  #1  0x420220e3 in wifi_free at /home/runner/work/esp32-arduino-lib-builder/esp32-arduino-lib-builder/esp-idf/components/esp_wifi/src/wifi_netif.c:52
  #2  0x4208fa95 in esp_netif_free_rx_buffer at /home/runner/work/esp32-arduino-lib-builder/esp32-arduino-lib-builder/esp-idf/components/esp_netif/lwip/esp_netif_lwip.c:960
  #3  0x42031b38 in lwip_netif_wifi_free_rx_buffer at /home/runner/work/esp32-arduino-lib-builder/esp32-arduino-lib-builder/esp-idf/components/lwip/port/esp32/netif/wlanif.c:67
  #4  0x4202555d in pbuf_free at /home/runner/work/esp32-arduino-lib-builder/esp32-arduino-lib-builder/esp-idf/components/lwip/lwip/src/core/pbuf.c:783
      (inlined by) pbuf_free at /home/runner/work/esp32-arduino-lib-builder/esp32-arduino-lib-builder/esp-idf/components/lwip/lwip/src/core/pbuf.c:729
  #5  0x42075a80 in AsyncClient::_recv(tcp_pcb*, pbuf*, signed char) at .pio/libdeps/esp32-s3-devkitc-1/AsyncTCP/src/AsyncTCP.cpp:1007
      (inlined by) AsyncClient::_recv(tcp_pcb*, pbuf*, signed char) at .pio/libdeps/esp32-s3-devkitc-1/AsyncTCP/src/AsyncTCP.cpp:983
  #6  0x42075b25 in AsyncClient::_s_recv(void*, tcp_pcb*, pbuf*, signed char) at .pio/libdeps/esp32-s3-devkitc-1/AsyncTCP/src/AsyncTCP.cpp:1375 
  #7  0x4207640e in _async_service_task(void*) at .pio/libdeps/esp32-s3-devkitc-1/AsyncTCP/src/AsyncTCP.cpp:170
      (inlined by) _async_service_task at .pio/libdeps/esp32-s3-devkitc-1/AsyncTCP/src/AsyncTCP.cpp:205


You are putting the code that supposed to be in the setup() (i.e. run once to configure things up) in the loop() and running it repeatedly. Learn from the WiFi examples that come with the ESP32 installation and the ESPAsyncWebServer README to understand what needs to be in setup() and what need to be in loop(). Put all the code into one single file and make it work before you try to optimise it or split into multiple files.

enter code here

I have changed it, still showing the error.I have used monitor_filters = esp32_exception_decoder
it is showing Possible Causes:
Null pointer dereference: Something in your code is attempting to access a null or invalid memory address. The backtrace shows that it happens in the WiFi and AsyncTCP layers.
Memory management issues: If a buffer is being freed twice or not properly managed, it could lead to crashes.

Please edit your post and add a section to include your updated code then and post the the backtrace if you can't solve it yourself.

I have edited the post,please  check it.

Did you read the AsyncTCPWebServer README or see the example to understand how the AsyncTCPWebServer code work? For AsyncTCPWebServer, all the setup of event handlers such as server.on() must be run in the setup(), not in the loop().

Running TCP client while the WiFi is not initialized will cause the system to crash. You need to deinitialize all TCP related instances before disabling WiFi.
